# Z3 create two intVectors with same elements but different order

Tags: z3, z3py

I need to have a duplicate Vector with the same values but the duplicate having a different order.
However I do not know how to set this constraint.

At the moment I am creating the Vectors like following:

```
age = RealVector('age', NUM)
age_med_all = RealVector('age_m_a', NUM)

s.add([age[i] == age_med_all[i] for i in range(NUM)])
s.add([age_med_all[i] <= age_med_all[i + 1] for i in range(NUM - 1)])
```

So actually I want the second Vector to be sorted to use it for an median constraint, while the original Vector should no need to be sorted.

So how can I change that line somehow to get `age[i] ==  age_med_all[j]`

```
s.add([age[i] == age_med_all[i] for i in range(NUM)])
```

I tried it like this:

```
for j in range(NUM) :
    s.add(Sum([If(age[i] == age_med_all[j], 1, 0) for i in range(NUM)]) >= 1)
```

however, when I do it like this, the two vectors do not consits of the same values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to convert your lists to bags and check that they're equal to each other. (A bag is essentially an array that stores the multiplicity of each element you store in it.)

Based on this idea, here's an example implementation:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

# Working on 10 elements
SIZE = 10

# a is the original arary, sortedA will be the sorted version of it
a       = IntVector('A', SIZE)
sortedA = IntVector('S', SIZE)

# Assert that sortedA is indeed sorted
for i in range(SIZE-1):
    s.add(sortedA[i] <= sortedA[i+1])

# convert them to bags:
bagA = K(IntSort(), 0)
bagS = K(IntSort(), 0)
for i in range(SIZE):
    bagA = Store(bagA, a[i],       1 + Select(bagA, a[i]))
    bagS = Store(bagS, sortedA[i], 1 + Select(bagS, sortedA[i]))

# assert that the bags are the same
s.add(bagA == bagS)

# a few constraints to make output interesting. obviously you'll
# have actual constraints, so these won't be needed
s.add(a[3] == 5)    # a fixed element
s.add(a[3] > a[9])  # out-of order

# get and print the model
r = s.check()
if r == sat:
    m = s.model()
    finalA = []
    finalS = []
    for i in range(SIZE):
        finalA.append(m.evaluate(a[i],       model_completion=True))
        finalS.append(m.evaluate(sortedA[i], model_completion=True))
    print("A = %s" % finalA)
    print("S = %s" % finalS)
else:
    print("Solver said: %s" % r)
```

I commented the code so it should be easy to follow, but feel free to ask if there's anything unclear.

When I run this program, I get:

```
A = [4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, -2, 3, -2]
S = [-2, -2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

You can verify that `S` is indeed the sorted version of `A`. (Depending on your version of z3, random seed, etc., you might of course get a different answer. But `S` should still be the sorted version of `A`.)